# Representation of linear operator between $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I was wondering where I could find a reference to the a characterization of continuous linear operators:
$$T:L^p(X,\mu)\to L^q(Y,\eta)$$

of the form $T(f)(y)=\int_{X} k(x,y)f(x)d\mu$ for some $k$ satisfying some properties.

Comment: The question is not properly stated. The form you are looking for is not sated clearly, but I guess you want $T$ to an integral operator. The answer depends on what type of properties you are interested in. If $p=q=2$, for example, not every operator on $L^{2}$ is compact and integral operators of interest are usually compact operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every bounded linear operator from $L^p$ to $L^q$ has an integral kernel. Schachermeyer (*Integral Operators on $L^p$ Spaces*, Indiana Uni. Math. J.) gave the following characterization of integral operators:

> Let $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $q\in [0,\infty]$. A linear operator $T\colon
>  L^p(X,\mu)\to L^q(Y,\nu)$ has an integral kernel if and only if it
>   maps order intervals to equi-measurable sets.

An order interval is a set of the form $\{f\in L^p(X,\mu)\mid g\leq f\leq h\}$ for $g,h\in L^p$. A subset $\mathfrak{F}$ of $L^q(Y,\nu)$ is called equi-measurable if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a measurable subset $Y_\epsilon$ of $Y$ such that $\nu(Y\setminus Y_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ and $\mathfrak{F}|_{Y_\epsilon}$ is relatively norm compact in $L^\infty(Y_\epsilon,\mu|_{Y_\epsilon})$.

Related results can be found in the articles *Kernel operators* and *Compactness properties of an operator which imply that it is an integral operator* by Schep, and *The integral representation of linear operators* by Buhvalov.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly one type of result I was searching for! Do you know how not integral operators look like?